# IP Extraction google analytics

Tags: filter, google-analytics

I try to add IP Extraction filter in google analytics for show visitor ip! but i cant see `Visitor IP Address` value in **`Field A -> Extract A`** custom dropdown! what's problem? how to work google analytics for show visitor ip ?!

how to work IP Extracion :

```
google analytics->admin->filtersTabs->newfilter 

name : IP Extraction
Filter Type : Custom filter -> Advanced
Field A -> Extract A : Visitor IP Address / (.*) //problem !!!
Output To -> Constructor: User Defined / $A1
```

screen : 
[image]

Comment: If you're in control of your server, you can simply log the IP addresses yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get the `Visitor IP` with Google Analytics:

> Due to user privacy concerns, Google Analytics doesn't report on
>   personally identifiable information, including a visitor's IP address. ...

Source: [Is there a report that displays IP addresses?](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=86214)

Comment: You could use a custom variable, but it is a violation of the terms of service. http://ryanunderdown.com/analytics/track-ip-addresses-in-google-analytics.php